# How can I hide username@node in linux shell?

Tags: linux, shell, solaris

I want to hide `username@solaris` in a Unix shell.

I would like something like this:

```
$ ls -l
```

Instead I have this:

```
user@solaris:~$ ls -l
```

Comment: This isn't a programming question

Answer (score 11):

If by "something *like*" you mean: '$' when normal user, '#' when root then put

```
PS1=\$
```

in your `.profile`

Otherwise use

```
PS1=$
```

Comment: This makes a good point.  You should use different prompts for root vs other users like CharString suggests.

Answer (score 8):

In `/etc/bashrc` or `~/.bashrc` change the `PS1` environment variable to `PS1=$`.  Or add a new line if no `PS1` already exists with:

```
PS1=$
```

Then, run this:

```
source /etc/bashrc
```

Or:

```
source ~/bashrc
```